Is it possible to dynamically switch databases in Looker Studio for multiple store reports

I'm using MySQL Google Connectors to connect to multiple store databases in Looker Studio. Each store has its own database named with the pattern gfan_[city initial]1 (e.g., gfan_smg1, gfan_asd1, gfan_qwe1).
Current setup:

Database connection example:
Host: [redacted]
Port: 3306
Database: gfan_smg1
Username: gfan_smg1
I have created a Looker Studio report for one store.
To create reports for other stores, I manually duplicate the report and change the database connection.

Problem:
I can't find a way to dynamically change the database connection within a single Looker Studio report, such as using a dropdown or button.
This leads to maintenance issues:

I have to create separate reports for each store.
When updating the report, I need to manually change every query in each duplicate.

Question:
Is there a way to dynamically switch between different store databases in a single Looker Studio report? If not, what are some efficient workarounds to manage reports for multiple stores with similar schemas but different database names?
